# Invertibility of integers modulo $20$

Tags: ring-theory, inverse

**Find the Number of elements which are not invertible in the set of integers $\{0, 1, 2, 3, ..... 19\}$ modulo $20$.**

*Approach:*
I have tried finding the elements which satisfies
$k$*(element) mod $20 = 1$ where $k>1;$ the elements which satisfy the equation indeed are the co-primes of $20.$
There are $12$ such elements. Is this correct?

Comment: do you mean in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$?

Comment: There are $12$ elements which are *not* coprime with $20$ and these are the noninvertible elements.  Meanwhile there are *eight* elements which are coprime and are the invertible elements.  Make sure you understand why and how to count these.

Comment: I found your wording a bit confusing. You are correct that the invertible elements are those prime to 20. There are 8 of them. So, the remaining 12 are not invertible. You can allow $k$ to be 1 since 1 is certainly invertible. The description of your approach, at least at a quick reading, gives the impression you are saying there are 12 elements prime to 20. Always be careful that what you write is what you mean to say.

Comment: got it , thanks..there will be 8 such elements and the other 12 are non-invertible

Comment: Reference topic : Totient function. That's totient, not quotient.

Answer (score 1):

The prime factorization of $20$ is $2^2\times5$, so multiples of $2$ and $5$ are not invertible modulo $20$.

That leaves the following $8$ invertible residues modulo $20$:  $1, 3, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17$, and $19.$

Accordingly, [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) of $20$, $\phi(20)=\phi(4)\times\phi(5)=2\times4=8.$